# Implementing Angular Material Table in my web-app : ERROR : Can't bind to 'mat' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-header-row'

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to implement an Angular Material Table in my web-app. Unfortunately i've got this error :

"Can't bind to 'mat' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-header-row'"

courses.component.html :

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="courses" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="categorie">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Categorie</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.categorie}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="urlImage">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Image Url</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.urlImage}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

     <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.price | currency }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
  
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

courses.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from 'src/app/modules/courses/services/course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-courses',
  templateUrl: './admin-courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-courses.component.css']
})

export class AdminCoursesComponent implements OnInit {

  courses!:any[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'description','categorie','urlImage','price'];
  constructor(private serviceCourse:CourseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceCourse.getAllCourses()
                      .subscribe(courses=>this.courses=courses)
                                          
  }
}
```

file "app.module.ts" of my module "admin" :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminCoursesComponent } from './components/admin-courses/admin-courses.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { CoursesComponent } from '../courses/components/courses/courses.component';
import { AppModuleCourses } from '../courses/app.module';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [AdminCoursesComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatTableModule,
        AppModuleCourses,

        ],
    exports:[AdminCoursesComponent],
    entryComponents:[CoursesComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [],
  })
  export class AppModuleAdmin { }
```

General app file of the app : "app.module.ts" :

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    
    import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
    import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
    import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
    import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
    import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
    import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
    import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
    
    // import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
    
    // import { AppModuleAdmin } from './modules/admin/app.module';
    import { AppModuleAuth } from './modules/authen/app.module';
    import { AppModuleCommun } from './modules/commun/app.module';
    import { AppModuleCourses } from './modules/courses/app.module';
    import { AppModuleMenu } from './modules/menu/app.module';
    import { LoginService } from './modules/authen/services/login.service';
    import { AppModuleUsers } from './modules/users/app.module';
    import { CourseService } from './modules/courses/services/course.service';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
       
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig, 'project-firebase'),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatCardModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        CommonModule,
    
        // MatToolbarModule,
        // AppModuleAdmin,
        AppModuleAuth,
        AppModuleCommun,
        AppModuleCourses,
        AppModuleMenu,
        AppModuleUsers,
        
    
    
      ],
      providers: [LoginService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Error message in the console :

NG0303: Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-header-row'.

Do I forgot to import a module in my admin-courses.component.ts ? I'm blocked ... Do you have any idea ?

For information, I try to solve using that code in my component.html file but it doesn't solve the problem (still have the same error message) :

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="courses" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Categorie </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.categorie}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Image Url </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.urlImage}} </td>
    </ng-container>

     <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Use   `<th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell></th><td *matCellDef="let e" mat-cell></td>`

Comment: From version 6+ `angular-material` replaced these elements by attributes

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I tried but i obtained the same result